# GIT replace branch's contents

Tags: git, git-merge

I've got a bare repo setup with the following branches:

```
dev
*master
stage
prod
```

I've cloned this to a working copy and issued the following commands:

```
git checkout -b stage remotes/origin/stage
git checkout -b dev remotes/origin/dev
```

What I need to do is push the entire contents of my staging branch into my dev branch.  Basically, this is a first-time setup, and I started with pushing production code into a staging branch (worked flawlessly) and now I'm pushing my staging code into the dev branch.

The problem I'm encountering is a merge conflict on binary files.  How do I tell git to not even LOOK at merge-conflicts, and instead just straight up copy over the contents of the stage branch into the dev branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided the simplest way to fix it was to do this:

clone the repo twice, once into a dev folder once into a stage folder
then

```
cd dev
git rm -rf *
git commit -a -m "take that n00b repo!"
git push
cp -r ../stage/* .
git add *
git commit -a -m "how you like dem apples??"
git push
```

Inelegant but it got the job done, and was a lot less painful than dealing with git's merge conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like `--s ours` option of `merge` is right what you need.

http://book.git-scm.com/5_advanced_branching_and_merging.html

Comment: Interesting, can you git remote add a repo you've cloned from?  Seems like that wouldn't be allowed...

Comment: @JohnZ The only thing that could block it is the name collision. There can't be 2 `origin` remotes, but many remotes with the same URL as the `origin`al.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Merge with the "ours" strategy
2. Merge normally and then amend the merge commit after with 'git checkout HEAD^ -- .'
3. Reset the dev branch to point to staging with 'git reset --hard staging'
4. Don't merge but just commit what's in staging after 'git checkout staging -- .'

Options 1 and 3 are probably best. You need to know the DAG (google "git for computer scientist").

We use this work flow: https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR

It's been very good for us.